# Put the first letter of each column in eol

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a file like this:

```
A_City,QQQQ
B_State,QQQQ
C_Country,QQQQ
A_Cityt,YYYY
B_State,YYYY
C_Country,YYYY
```

I want to add one more column at end of the line on the same file with the first letter of each column.

```
A_City,QQQQ,AQ
B_State,QQQQ,BQ
C_Country,QQQQ,CQ
A_Cityt,YYYY,AY
B_State,YYYY,BY
C_Country,YYYY,CY
```

I would like to get this using sed but if there is an awk code would help.

Comment: Only separately, tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' < File.csv | sed -e 's/^\(.\).*/,\1/g' .
but it brings me only the First letter of the first column.
I did cut -d"," -f1,8 file.csv, however, I need to put it at end of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{print $0 "," substr($0,1,1) substr($0,length($0))}' file

A_City,QQQQ,AQ
B_State,QQQQ,BQ
C_Country,QQQQ,CQ
A_Cityt,YYYY,AY
B_State,YYYY,BY
C_Country,YYYY,CY
```

or, perhaps

```
$ awk -F, '{print $0 FS substr($1,1,1) substr($2,1,1)}' file
```

Comment: This awk did not work very well. 
In this awk get the last position of the second column. I know it sucks but sometimes I will receive data with A_City,DDYY, that's why I need the first column.

Comment: awk '{print $0 "," substr($0,1,1) substr($1,8,1)}' file
Thats the result I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

When you have only one `,` you can use

```
sed -r 's/^(.).*,(.).*/&,\1\2/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed -r 's/^|,+/&\n/g;s/$/,\n/;:a;s/\n(.).*,\n.*/&\1/;s/\n//;/\n.*,\n/ba;s/\n//g' file
```

Insert a newline at the start of a line or following one or more `,`'s. Append an additional `,` and a newline to the end of the line. Append a character following a newline followed by zero or more characters followed by a `,` and a final newline and any following characters to its match. Remove the first newline. If there are two or more newlines repeat. Finally remove all newlines.

N.B. If the line is initially empty, this will add a `,` to such lines. Empty fields are catered for and will be represented by no first character.